# What could be the reason for this WCF error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, wcf-binding

My WCF service[using basicHttpBinding] is hosted on IIS 6.Am able to access it using ?wsdl in the service url in  IE browser .

I've a presenation layer in my winforms client and I added the reference of this service using ServiceReferences option in VS.Net which then  generated a proxy.

When I call a method on this service, am getting this exception.What could I be missing here ?Thanks.

> "Value cannot be null.Parameter name uri."  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientViaBehavior..ctor(Uri uri)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ClientViaElement.CreateBehavior()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadBehaviors[T](ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1
>   behaviorElement, KeyedByTypeCollection`1 behaviors, Boolean
>   commonBehaviors)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String
>   configurationName, EndpointAddress address)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1
>   endpointTrait)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()     at
>   TestingClient..ctor() in C:\Presentation\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 268

Here is my config xml for server and client:

*Server:

```
<system.serviceModel> 
    <bindings> 
      <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="ProviderBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" 
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"> 
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> 
          <security mode="Transport"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" /> 
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" /> 
          </security> 
        </binding> 
      </basicHttpBinding> 
    </bindings> 
    <services> 
      <service name="PTSWeb.PriceTestingService" behaviorConfiguration="PTSWeb.Service1Behavior"> 
        <!-- Service Endpoints --> 
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PTSWeb.IPriceTesting"> 
          <identity> 
            <dns value="localhost"/> 
          </identity> 
        </endpoint> 
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
      </service> 
    </services> 
    <behaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="PTSWeb.Service1Behavior"> 
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> 
        </behavior> 
      </serviceBehaviors> 
    </behaviors> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

*Client:

```
<system.serviceModel> 
    <client> 
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/PTSWeb/PTSWebService.svc" 
        behaviorConfiguration="PTSWeb.Service1Behavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="IPriceTestingBinding" contract="IPriceTesting" 
        name="IPriceTestingPort" /> 
      <endpoint address="https://qaserver/webservice" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProviderBinding" 
                contract="Provider" name="ProviderPort" />      
    </client> 
    <bindings> 
      <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="IPriceTestingBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true"> 
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" 
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> 
          <security mode="None" /> 
        </binding> 
        <binding name="ProviderBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" 
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"> 
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> 
          <security mode="Transport"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" /> 
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" /> 
          </security> 
        </binding> 
      </basicHttpBinding> 
    </bindings> 

    <behaviors> 
      <endpointBehaviors>      
        <behavior name="PTSWeb.Service1Behavior"> 
          <clientVia/> 
        </behavior> 
      </endpointBehaviors> 
  </behaviors> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please show both ServiceModel config  (client/server)

Comment: Sure VdesmedT.Have now added xml details in my question.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the client config behavior, you have a ClientVia element without any URI defined. Either remove this behavior or define the via Uri.

This quite well explain the goal and usage of the clientvia behavior : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anilkumargupta/archive/2009/05/16/wcf-intermediate-service-between-client-and-server.aspx

Comment: Yes, I could figure this out when I compared my client xml with the one generated using AddServiceReference in VS.Net.And stacktrace also points to LoadChannelBehaviors method.I commented out behavior node and removed its reference from the end point node in my client xml.It worked fine.Thanks VdesmedT for your inputs anyway.